# How remove prompt messages on nexus 4 root?

Tags: root-access, nexus-4, 5.0-lollipop

Is it possible to make warning messages not appear? Example, when I try to turn off 'Cellular data' in data usage, I get the stupid question "turn off..?"

Is it possible to force the phone to do as you tell it without it playing smart asking you before executing?

Answer (score 0):

You can toggle cellular data from quick settings.

1. Swipe downwards twice to bring up the toggles.
2. Tap on the mobile network icon, which will open up another screen
   which shows the total data usage.
3. Then switch on/off the cellular data from this screen.

When you use this navigation, it won't throw a confirmation dialog.